# Как открыть цифровую клавиатуру на телефоне при вводе в input type="text"?

Tags: html, jquery, html5, вёрстка, input

Как при вводе в `input type="text"` открыть на мобильных цифровую клавиатуру?
Или при вводе в `input type="number"` ограничить всё, кроме ввода цифр и запятой?
Проблем в том, что при наличию точки в конце без десятичного знака, `input` возвращает пустоту.
Я пробовал биндить регулярки, но `input type="number"` вообще не реагирует на них.

Мб я вообще неправильное решение ищу?
Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе цифр десятичного числа на телефоне, открывалась цифровая клавиатура и всё правильно считалось — при вводе `"45."` на расчёт шло `"45"`, а не `""`. Причём я заметил что `input type="number"` пропускает точку, запятую и цифры, вот когда используется запятая, всё окей — то есть, при вводе `"45,"` в расчёт идёт `"45"`, а при вводе `"45."` в расчёт `""` и результат 0.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7yrhodjv/ - воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку при вводе `input[type=number]` ведёт себя не совсем адекватно при вводе точки, предлагаю вот такой костыль с `input[type=hidden]`. При сабмите формы берите значение из него — там всегда будет храниться нужное значение.

Немного объяснений по коду:

1. При событии `keydown` отлавливаем нажатие на точку или дробную часть (у точки на нампаде другой код) и записываем в `input[type=hidden]` текущее значение + точку. Также отлавливаем бекспейс + проверяем — есть ли точка в предпоследнем символе в `input[type=number]`, и если есть, то удаляем цифру после точки.
2. Событие `keyup` срабатывает уже после того, как символ появился в `input[type=number]` и, если его значение `true`, то добавляем его в `input[type=hidden]`. Если оно равно `false` + была нажата клавиша бекспейс + старое значение `input[type=hidden]` содержит один символ, то значит мы стерли все символы и `input[type=hidden]` надо приравнять пустому значению.
3. Эти же действия дублируются на ивент `input`, чтобы можно было вводить значение стрелочками или колесом мыши.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=number]'),
  hidden = document.querySelector('input[type=hidden]'),
  output = document.querySelector('output');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 110 || e.keyCode === 190) {
    hidden.value = e.target.value + '.';
  } else if (e.keyCode === 8 && e.target.value.slice(-2, -1) === '.') {
    hidden.value = hidden.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', inputProcess);
input.addEventListener('input', inputProcess);

function inputProcess(e) {
  if (input.value) {
    hidden.value = input.value;
  } else if (!input.value && e.keyCode === 8 && hidden.value.length === 1) {
    hidden.value = '';
  }
  
  output.innerHTML = hidden.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
<input type="hidden" />
<br>
<output></output>
```

Comment: пожалуйста :) по возможности отпишите сработало это решение для разных видов телефонов или нет.

Comment: На телефоне к сожалению не завелось :( На Декстопе отлично работает, на Телефоне точка не фиксится..

Comment: какая ОС, какой браузер?